# SceneKit : Crash with SCNReferenceNode load

Tags: animation, runtime-error, scenekit, arkit

I develop an AR project. 
In my scene I use SCNReferenceNode to load external content. 
The first time, I execute the code, everything is OK. 
When I return to the homepage and reaccess to my scene, I've got a crash when I use load() for SCNReferenceNode. Crash occurs not every time. Sometimes, load() method don't crash my app. I test many things but nothing work.

Here is a part of my code when I use **load()** on **SCNReferenceNode** :

```
let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "model", withExtension: "scn", subdirectory: "map.scnassets")!

self.refNode = SCNReferenceNode(url: url)!
self.container.addChildNode(self.refNode)
self.refNode.load()
```

When I return on home, I try to clean my scene :

```
self.refNode.unload()
self.refNode = nil
```

But when I return in my scene (second time access), I've got a crash 'Bad Exec' :

```
0x1dbf6d048 <+40>:  bl     0x1dbdbe374               ; C3DAnimationManagerRemoveAnimationsForObject
0x1dbdbe3ac <+56>:  cbz    x0, 0x1dbdbe3f8           ; <+132>
0x1a7d9562c <+100>: ldr    x9, [x0]
```

On stack, I see **'C3DAnimationManagerRemoveAnimationsForObject'** so I suppose the problem is going from an animation. I'll try to remove all actions, all loops...

I try to use **Instruments**(for zombies, leaks..), **breakpoints** but I'm to noob !!!

How can I find a solution, how can I resolve this error ?
Thanks in adavance...

Comment: what if you do not use the unload(), but only setting it to nil ?

Comment: Unfortunately, always the same error...

Comment: do you use some other frameworks for stuff that could hold references to your nodes? What, if you use a common node instead of a reference node?

Comment: Yes , I use different frameworks. If I keep a reference of my SCNReferenceNode and reuse it the second time, that's work... But if I reload it, crash... How can I inspect references ? I find that C3DAnimationManager is only appear in SCNMaterialProperty.